# Html Agility Pack - XPath can't use contains

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I got following problem:
I'm using the XPath feature of the Html Agility Pack to navigate through some HTML.

I tried following XPath in my browser (Firebug - XPath Extension) and it worked fine:

```
//tr[contains(@data-link-to, '/test/')]
```

Sadly Html Agility Pack doesn't seem to find it. If I try the direct path (html/body/etc) it works.

Is there a work-around that I can use? I want to find all table rows that have the attribute "data-link-to" that containts "/test/".

Am I doing something wrong? Does the Html Agility Pack use an older version of XPath?

Example of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta content="en" name="locale">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
        <header>
        <article>
            <table>
            <thead></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-link-to="/test/1">
                    <tr data-link-to="/test/2">
                    <tr data-link-to="/test/3">
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </article>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works

```
 //section/article/table/tbody/tr
```

This doesn't work

```
//tr[contains(@data-link-to, '/test/')]
```

Obviously the working solution is really error prone.

Comment: Without seeing the associated HTML it's difficult to say. Include the relevant section of the actual source code (i.e. "view source", not the developer tools' DOM representation). For reference also include the first two or three lines of the document that contain the document type and the `<html>` element.

Comment: I added an example to my question. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You did not add the first two or three lines of the document as they appear in the original source. I asked for those lines for a reason.

Comment: I'm sorry... I added the remaining lines above the <html> element. I'm not sure if that really helps.

Comment: Okay, I wanted to make sure that you are not dealing with XHTML here. What do `//tr` and `//tr[@data-link-to]` give you, respectively?

Comment: They both give me the three table rows? The problem is that the real HTML page has other tablre rows with other data-link-to that I'm not interested in. I'm sorry if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: Do you get three table rows that actually contain the correct `@data-link-to` values? Because if that's the case, then `//tr[contains(@data-link-to, '/test/')]` should work as well.

Comment: The XPath //tr[@data-link-to] works => gives me three rows / a list of three HtmlNodes; The XPath //tr[contains(@data-link-to, '/test/'')] doesn't work. =>the result is always empty / null

Comment: Try it incrementally to figure out where it beaks, that's what I am trying to tell you here. What about `//tr[contains(@data-link-to, '/')]`? If that works, add a letter. And so on, until you found the culprit.

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak! The culprit is the special character / . Right now I don't understand why it doesn't work but if I use `//tr[contains(@data-link-to, 'test')]` it works!